# Export/Import THREE.js scene objects

Tags: three.js

I need to save all objects in scene (to database) and then load them from there. For this I need somehow to serialize that objects in, say, JSON to save all verties, faces, matherial and other information. I see [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters) few exporters but there seems to be no one I can use from my application to export THREE.js objects. I also found [`.toJSON`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js#L570) method in `Object3D` that use appropriate methods of [`Geometry`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Geometry.js#L800) and  [`Material`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/materials/Material.js#L110). But because of [this odd code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/5c7e0df9b100ba40cdcaaf530196290e16c34858/src/core/Geometry.js#L814) in Geometry:

```
    if ( this.parameters !== undefined ) {

        var parameters = this.parameters;

        for ( var key in parameters ) {

            if ( parameters[ key ] !== undefined ) output[ key ] = parameters[ key ];

        }

        return output;

    }
```

I receive objects without faces and verices:

[image]

What are `this.parameters`? Even If I comment above code, I will have faces and verices but without such important properties like `position`, `rotation`, `receiveShadow` and so on. So how can I export/import THREE.js scene objects?

Comment: You should look at SceneExporter.js in the examples directory.

Comment: @gaitat, with SceneExporter I have another question - how to import that back into three.js application? I tried `ObjectLoader` but it gives error `Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

Comment: there are `SceneLoader` but is in folder `deprecated` so is it ok to use it?

Comment: I guess there are some issues: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3368

Comment: @SET Did you find a solution to this problem?